# Fibonacci series sum

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, i, n, sum = 0 ;
  printf("Enter the limit : ") ;
  scanf("%d", &n) ;
  printf("\nThe fibonacci series is :") ;
  for(i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
  {
   c = a + b ;
   printf("%d-", c) ;
   sum = sum + c ;
   a = b ;
   b = c ;
  }
  printf("\nThe sum of the fibonacci series is : %d", sum) ;
  printf("\n");
}
```

Now I need to find the term of the series that makes the sum bigger than 7 digits, how can I do that?
P.S I am new to `C` and sorry for my English.

Comment: If this is a real problem, use maths instead of for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first sum of seven digits, set your threshold to one million, also known as `1e6 = 10**6 = 1000000`. Notice that there are seven digits in `1000000`.

If you want the sum to have more than seven digits, set the threshold to ten million. That number has eight digits.

The following code will do the trick. Note that instead of a `for` loop, we have a `while` loop that keeps iterating while the sum is less than the threshold.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int previous, current = 0, next = 1,
      sum = current, threshold;
  printf("Enter the threshold: ") ;
  scanf("%d", &threshold) ;
  printf("Fibonacci series: %d", current) ;
  while (sum < threshold) {
    previous = current;
    current = next;
    next = previous + current;
    printf(" + %d", current) ;
    sum += current;
  }
  printf(" = %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not a `if` loop it's a `for` loop!

Comment: soething's wrong with the treshold, for example I enter a treshold of 20 and I get a sum of 20, isn't the treshold supposed to be be bigger than the sum? thanks

Comment: In the code above, the fibonacci series continues until the sum is **at least as great as** the threshold. If you want the sum to exceed the threshold, just change the `while` condition from `(sum < threshold)` to `(sum <= threshold)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, i, n, term1, term2;
 long sum = 0;
 printf("Enter the limit : ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("\nThe fibonacci series is :");
 for(i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
 {
  c = a + b ;
  printf("%d \n", c) ;
  sum = sum + c ;
  if(sum >= 1000000){
  term1 = a;
  term2 = b;
  break;
  }
a = b ;
b = c ;
}

printf("\nThe sum of the fibonacci series is : %ld", sum);
printf("\n terms are %d and %d", term1, term2);
printf("\n");
}
```

This program breaks from the loop when it finds the right terms that makes sum more that 7 digits.
Hope I understood what you meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code as little as possible:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int a = -1, b = 1, c = 0, i = 1, n = 0, sum = 0 ;
    printf("\nThe fibonacci series is :") ;
    while (sum <= 10000000)
    {
        c = a + b ;
        printf("%d-", c) ;
        sum = sum + c ;
        a = b ;
        b = c ;
        n = i;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of the fibonacci series is : %d", sum) ;
    printf("\nThe term is %d the value is %d", n , c);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes 8 digits which is greater than 7 digits.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this (You have to declare `number` and `found = 0` at the top(line 4)):

```
    if(sum >= 1000000 && !found) {
        specialNumber = fibonacci;
        found = 1;
    }
```

So it checks if the sum get's bigger then a 7 digit number! And if yes the last fibonacci  number was then number you search, which is the number that makes the sum bigger then 7 digits! And found is that only the first number is assign to specialNumber.

So you program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int count, sum, specialNumber, fibonacci, numberOne, numberTow, found;
    sum = 0, fibonacci = 0, numberOne = -1, numberTow = 1, found = 0;
    int n;

    printf("Enter the limit :\n>") ;
    scanf("%d", &n) ;

    printf("\nThe fibonacci series is :") ;
    for(count = 1 ; count <= n ; count++) {
        fibonacci = numberOne + numberTow;
        printf("\n%d", fibonacci);
        sum += fibonacci;
        if(sum >= 1000000 && !found) {
            specialNumber = fibonacci;
            found = 1;
        }

        numberOne = numberTow;
        numberTow = fibonacci;
    }

    printf("\nThe sum of the fibonacci series is : %d\n", sum);
    printf("%d makes the sum bigger than 7 digits", specialNumber);

  return 0;

}
```